# Capture live output of a subprocess whithout blocking it

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

I am currently writing a script that will need at some point to capture the output of a heavy `grep` command.

The problem is, I can't obtain decent performance from the command compared to just running in the shell. (It appears to be at least 2x slower, sometimes never ending). I'm grepping a whole partition (that's part of the purpose of the script), I know it's a slow operation, I'm talking about the huge difference between runtime in the shell and in my python script.

I've struggled with it for quite some time. Tried the queue library, threading, multiprocessing, gave asyncio a bit of a shot. I'm getting really lost.

I've shortened it to simplest form, here it is :

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p = Popen(['grep', '-a', '-b', 'MyTestString', '/dev/sda1'], stdin = None, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, bufsize=-1)

while True:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    if output:
        print(output.strip())
```

So here, my `grep` command is way slower than in the shell. I've tried putting a `time.sleep` in my main loop but it seems to be worse.

Just a few more infos :

- There will be very few output from the command.
- The final goal would be to grab the output without blocking the main thread but one problem at time.
- Again, I know that my grep command is a heavy one

Thanks for your help if you have any idea or suggestion. I'm on the verge of despair :(

Answer (score 0):

Your coding should be (so that you eventually terminate):

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

# specify text = True to read unicode strings rather than byte strings:
# don't pipe stderr if you will not be reading it:    
p = Popen(['grep', '-a', '-b', 'MyTestString', '/dev/sda1'], stdout = PIPE, text = True)

while True:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    if output:
        print(output, end='')
    else:
        break
p.wait()
```

The only explanation I can come up with for the performance difference is if `grep` is finding a lot of matches (only you would know). When you run it from the command line, because the implementation is in the `C` language, after finding a match very little time is spent in outputting the matched line. But with your program we are dealing with interpreted Python and a pipe through which the matched line must travel and those two factors are slowing things down. Thus, it is not the matching that is slowing down but just the outputting of the match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The thing is I need to get the output while the command is still running. As the command execution is very long I need to get it on the go to process it afterwards.

Comment: In my code snippet I'm only printing it for testing purposes.

Comment: Well try the code that begins with "At the very least, you original coding should have been:" (note the `text = True` argument so that you are dealing with strings and not bytes and get rid of `stderr = PIPE`). **You *might* want to show your real code for it might explain what the slowdown is if you are are doing major processing, which you would not be doing when you run `grep` from the command line.** You ask why it is much slower when you run grep as a subprocess but then you hide the fact that you are doing something quite different and expect a good answer.

Comment: Please, why everybody so aggressive here :( 
This is my full code, I'm not hiding anything. 
Just tried `text = true` and removed `stderr = PIPE`, I didn't see any change sorry. 

So just to be clear I'm not doing any processing with the output for now. Again, this is the full code, but I will need to do it in the future so I'd like to have terminal-like (or at least decent) performances while getting live output. Not just waiting for the command to end.

Comment: I guess, even if my code is short there must be something blocking the Popen command. Probably `stdout.readline()`. I've tried some of the other options I could think of, as I've explain in my question post, but never could make a change.

Comment: Sorry; I misunderstood your previous comment. Actually I am not sure I understand the last argument to Popen, `/dev/sda1`. Is this a single file? `grep` takes one or more file sepcifcations (you *can* use wildcard specifications such as *.py, which get expanded into multiple files, but on Linux this requires that you pass to Popen the command as a single string rather than a list of strings and that you specify `shell=True`).

Comment: I've updated the answer with a *possible* explanation.